# R:Name the output of function same as input

Tags: r, function, save, output

I edit to specify my problem.
This is my dataset (for example)

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL",from="2013-01-01")
data<-AAPL
p1<-4   
dO<-data[,1]
dC<-data[,4]
emaO<-EMA(dO,n=p1)
emaC<-EMA(dC,n=p1)
fee<-0.1
cross<-ifelse((emaC<emaO & lag(emaC,1)>lag(emaO,1))|emaC>emaO & lag(emaC,1)<lag(emaO,1),"A","N")
type<-ifelse(emaC>emaO,"S",
             ifelse(emaC<emaO,"L","Equal"))
Pos_emaO_dO_UP<-emaO>dO
Pos_emaO_dO_D<-emaO<dO
Pos_emaC_dC_UP<-emaC>dC
Pos_emaC_dC_D<-emaC<dC
Pos_emaC_emaO_UP<-emaC>emaO
Pos_emaC_emaO_D<-emaC<emaO
Profit_L<-((((lag(dC,-1))-(lag(dO,-1)))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100)-fee
```

This should be a data.frame of how it looks like

```
df1<-data.frame(cross,type,Pos_emaO_dO_UP,Pos_emaO_dO_D,Pos_emaC_dC_UP,Pos_emaC_dC_D,Pos_emaC_emaO_UP,Pos_emaC_emaO_D,Profit_L)
colnames(df1)<-c("cross","type","Pos_emaO_dO_UP","Pos_emaO_dO_D","Pos_emaC_dC_UP","Pos_emaC_dC_D","Pos_emaC_emaO_UP","Pos_emaC_emaO_D","Profit_L")
conditions<-c(Pos_emaO_dO_UP,Pos_emaO_dO_D,Pos_emaC_dC_UP,Pos_emaC_dC_D,Pos_emaC_emaO_UP,Pos_emaC_emaO_D)
```

And I was maybe wrong to ask you for this function

```
savefun<-function(x){
  Condition<-deparse(substitute(x))
  f<-head(subset(table_1,prekrizeni=="A" & TYP1=="L" & x),-1)
  Success<-nrow(f[f$Zisk_L>0,])/nrow(f)
  d<-data.frame(Condition,Success)
  d
}
```

So I will tell you all I need to not be misunderstanded.
I want to make a function (or loop) which will be 2-step process.
1, I want go trough function savefun() ale of the conditions (First,second and so) and have a data.frame with all these results in form data.frame(Condition,Success) like it is in savefun() with n rows=length(conditions)
2, And at the end I want some kind of loop which repeat it until there is no Success column higher the higher of the previous. It means. Use savefun() for all conditions, choose the conditions with the highest Success column, take this condition and give it to savefun(), parameter f like this>

```
savefun<-function(x){
      Condition<-deparse(substitute(x))
      f<-head(subset(table_1,prekrizeni=="A" & TYP1=="L" & NEW_ADDED_CONDITION & x),-1)
      Success<-nrow(f[f$Zisk_L>0,])/nrow(f)
      d<-data.frame(Condition,Success)
      d
    }
```

Run the savefun() again on all conditions (instead the new_added_condition) and repeating this process until there is no combination with higher "the highest success" then previous one. Then stop the loop and show as result data.frame or just names of used conditions in last step before stop.
I hope it is clear, I will really apreciate your help, I've got to finish my school work and I am in time press. Thanks a lot again
@Richard Scriven  @Osssan

Comment: try if this works `assign("x",list(x=x,b=b),envir = .GlobalEnv)` and access it later using `get("x")`

Comment: Instead of `as.character(substitute(x))`, you might want `deparse(substitute(x))`

Comment: Thank you, I change it. It is better. Can you please help me with ""problem I mentioned above? I edit the Answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: for parsing through `vector`, `do.call(rbind,lapply(vector,function(x) savefun(x)))`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. It shows only 1 row as a result in data.frame

Comment: It would be much easier to solve if we had `table_1`

Comment: I will give specific example with data in a moment. Thank you a lot

Comment: Hi, I edited the question above, the table_1 (renamed to df_1) and data in it are there. Thank you a lot for help @Richard Scriven

Comment: Is `conditions` supposed to be a logical vector?  Or a character vector?

Comment: It is character vector, only the list of conditions which I need to go trough function. You can change it, if it is necessary.

Comment: If there is something I didn't explain clear, please tell it, I will do my best to make it clear. I'm still trying to finish it myself, but I cannot finish it. Hope I will be able to help you back someday...

Answer (score 0):

With `assign` and `get`

```
savefun<-function(x){
    f<-subset(table_1,prekrizeni=="A" & TYP1=="L" & x)
    b<-nrow(f[f$Zisk_L>0,])/nrow(f)
    assign('x',list(x=x,b=b),envir=.GlobalEnv)
    return(get('x',envir=.GlobalEnv))

}
```

Comment: Be careful with `assign`.  The way you've written it, `x` will be overwritten if it already exists in the global environment.